# FBSDKLikeControl is grayed-out/disabled

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, fbsdk, fbsdklikecontrol

I want to use Facebook like button in my app, but it is all grayed-out, and does not work. I've tried it with various `objectId`s, but none of them worked. I'm sure that I installed Facebook SDK right, because I have share button as well and it works just fine. What can be the matter? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FBSDKLikeControl](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/iossdk/current/FBSDKShareKit/classes/fbsdklikecontrol.html) is deprecated.

Comment: Not really helpful answer unless you mention how to fix it :)

Comment: I wish there was an alternative for iOS. I ended up using Like Button on the web, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button/